# QTest execute tests in method instead of main

Tags: c++, qt, methods, qtestlib

is there a way to execute QTest::qExec() in a classes method instead of a main()?
I NEED to have my testproject compiled as a dll instead of a standalone .exe.
The dll is used by an existing GUI, the test shall be executed by a button.

When qexec is called however, the QTGUI freezes and doesnt respond anymore.
The following is the implementation of the qt slot which handles the Buttons request to execute the test, later the results should be read and displayed in some QEdit widget (which works already whith dummy results).

```
int GUI_Form::onTestRequested()
{
const char* n_argv[] = { "-o", "dummy.txt"};
QCoreApplication CoreApp(argc, const_cast<char**>(n_argv)); 
QApplication app(argc, const_cast<char**>(n_argv));

return QTest::qExec(&mTestform, argc, const_cast<char**>(n_argv));
}
```

It compiles fine. Not implementing QCoreApplication and QApplication makes no functional difference, I added them because they are required in the usual main().

Comment: Why do you need another `QApplication` if you already have one (your GUI application)? I think your test slot should just do this: `return QTest::qExec(&mTestform, QStringList() << "-o" << "dummy.txt");`

Comment: @vahancho thanks for your comment. That was my guess too, but it doesnt work. I cant use the nice QStringList because of an old version of QT. Besides from that, it doesnt work without QApplication either. Do you have any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You can always wrap in a dll function that you export your call to your QTest::exec

Now, obviously if called from the Main thread of the (other) GUI application, it will freeze your GUI. You migth want to call it from a background thread (if your tests and classes under testare thread safe of course)